# Format of mail from Apple Mail version 7.3

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

My work colleagues, who use Outlook, complain that the e-mails I forward to them are not always readable, or have a lot of attachments.

Is there anything I can change on my side to prevent this from happening?

Comment: who is you email provider (Google, MSN, others ?

Comment: There is a huge difference between "not readable" and "lot of attachments". Which problem do you want to focus on? If on the first one, can you get your colleagues to provide a screenshot of an "not readable" mail and add it to the question?

Comment: The "lot of attachments" is more of a concern. The not readable is a result of the forwarded message received as an attachment which can't all be open by my colleague using windows and outlook

Comment: Using Google mail and a POP3 account hosted bby KonsoleH